# Why didn’t Gandalf violate the rules of engagement?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

The other Maia (Sauron and Saurman) had no trouble cheating in order to win Middle Earth and didn't get hit with bolts of lightning, so why didn't Gandalf go full-out like they did?

Sauron and Saurman almost won. The outcome was essentially balanced on the edge of a knife.

Comment: Sauron wasn’t bound by the Middle-Earth limitations that the Istari were, so he wasn’t really ‘cheating’ at all. He was quite rogue. Saruman broke the limitations he was under; he just switched sides. Granted, creating an Uruk-Hai army and sending it off to war is getting a bit more directly involved than the Istari were meant to be, but not significantly more so than Gandalf battling a Balrog, for instance.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It was *very* different. Gandalf exposed his power to defeat [a supernatural enemy of the Old World, something beyond almost anyone left in Middle-earth](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18923/). Saruman raised an army and tried to conquer the kingdoms of Men. *Significantly* different uses of power

Comment: @Jason Yes, significantly _different_, but I wouldn’t really say that one is really _more_ outside the ‘Istari rules’ than the other, except for the fact, of course, that switching sides and turning against Men would be outside the ‘Istari rules’ to begin with.

Comment: How well did Sauron and Saurman turn out? Not just their empires, but they themselves? Not just that they were defeated, but what kind of beings did they become? That's your answer.

Comment: It's fair to say Sauron wasn't subject to the rules, but Saruman certainly was.  He literally got fired for his antics.  Gandalf was already promoted to Saruman's position by the time they all had their yell-off at Orthanc.

Comment: Notice that the cheaters ***didn't*** win. Gandalf did. There could be an in-universe reason for that. Just because the cheaters weren't hit by bolts of lightning doesn't mean there weren't other consequences that might have been more subtle.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Very good point. They could have lost BECAUSE they cheated. Hmmmm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gandalf himself answers this (albeit obliquely) in the Council of Elrond:

> [I]t is not our part here to take thought only for a season, or for a few lives of Men, or for a passing age of the world. We should seek a final end of this menace
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 2: "The Council of Elrond"</sup>

Gandalf *could* have broken the Rules, but that would only have been a temporary solution that would have caused problems down the road; it's worth remembering *why* the Valar insisted on these restrictions for the Istari:

> [T]his the Valar did, desiring to amend the errors of old, especially that they had attempted to guard and seclude the Eldar by their own might and glory fully revealed
>
> <sup>*Unfinished Tales* Part 4 Chapter 2: "The Istari"</sup>

Sure, he may have won the battle for the Free Peoples, but he would have postponed the end of the War.